# retreive data on last create named range from previous inserted named range

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I have 3 named table : Table11, Table34, Table41.
The idea is that, any time I am inserting/adding a new table(lets say Table56), in the new table I need to add the data from previous inserted added table data: the values from columns Tax1, Tax2, Fees.
Sometimes the table might have additional columns and rows, which it shouldn't affect retrieving data from a previous table into a new table. Also, it might happen that the name of tables to be different, because the file is accessed by different users
The name of the table is added as a list in another worksheet when the table is created, for this I was able to create a small code using a template table (copy and paste).

[image]
[image]

So, is it possible to retrieve data in last named table from previous inserted named table?

Anyone can give me a helpful hand?

Answer (score 0):

### Update New Table With Data From Previously Added Table

[image]

```vb
Sub UpdateNewTable()
    
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const wsName As String = "Report"
    Const CriteriaHeader As String = "ID"
    Const sTableHeadersList As String _
        = "Wage,Tax1,Tax2,Fees"
    Const dTableHeadersList As String _
        = "Wage Previous,Tax1 Previous,Tax2 Previous,Fees Previous"
    
    ' Reference the objects.
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim tblCount As Long: tblCount = ws.ListObjects.Count
    If tblCount < 2 Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim stbl As ListObject: Set stbl = ws.ListObjects(tblCount - 1)
    Dim dtbl As ListObject: Set dtbl = ws.ListObjects(tblCount)
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = stbl.ListColumns(CriteriaHeader).DataBodyRange
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dtbl.ListColumns(CriteriaHeader).DataBodyRange
    
    ' Read data.
    
    ' A 2D one-based one-column array with the same number of rows
    ' as the source (one-column) range, holding the destination (table)
    ' row indexes where the source values were found.
    ' There will be error values for not found values ('IsNumeric').
    Dim drIndexes As Variant: drIndexes = Application.Match(srg, drg, 0)
    
    Dim sHeaders() As String: sHeaders = Split(sTableHeadersList, ",")
    Dim dHeaders() As String: dHeaders = Split(dTableHeadersList, ",")
    Dim hUpper As Long: hUpper = UBound(sHeaders)
    
    ' Write (copy) data.
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim hc As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(drIndexes) ' or '1 To srg.Rows.Count'
        If IsNumeric(drIndexes(sr, 1)) Then
            dr = drIndexes(sr, 1)
            For hc = 0 To hUpper
                dtbl.ListColumns(dHeaders(hc)).DataBodyRange.Rows(dr).Value _
                    = stbl.ListColumns(sHeaders(hc)) _
                        .DataBodyRange.Rows(sr).Value
            Next hc
        End If
    Next sr

    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "New table updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```